# Kibana scripted field

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kibana

I am trying to write a scripted field in Kibana 4.5.1 in order to extract the hour from the `@timestampt` field. I just followed the example in the following link but it gives me a parsing error:
https://www.elastic.co/blog/kibana-4-beta-3-now-more-filtery

Now in the link it says that this does not work starting from Kibana 4.0.0 since scripted field are now based on Lucene. So does anybody know what the equivalent code in Lucene would be? The Groovy expression is as follows: `Integer.parseInt(new Date(doc["@timestamp"].value).format("H"))` where `@timestamp` is the field's name which contains a date in the format `MMM dd HH:mm:ss.SSS` and I need to extract the `HH` values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They now use lucene expression:
`doc["creation_ts"].getHourOfDay()`

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/modules-scripting.html#_lucene_expressions_scripts

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#_lucene_expressions_scripts

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes the documentation is now up to date :)